# reenter string in text box if string not found

Tags: c#, loops, textbox

How to re enter a string in text box if string doesn't match?

code I'm trying is but it stucks in loop and does not allow me to enter string again in textbox.

Can anybody guide me how to do this

the code is:

```
public void userpass()
        {
            int us = 0; //for user pass
            string readText2 = File.ReadAllText(pathuser);
            using (StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(pathuser))
            {

                string usernam = username.Text;
                string line;
                string[] lines = new String[500];

                while ((line = sr2.ReadLine()) != null )
                {
                    lines[us] = line;


                    if (lines[us] == usernam && usernam != "")
                    {
                        check = 1;
                        MessageBox.Show(usernam);
                        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                        this.Hide();
                        break;
                    }
                    us++;
                }

                if (lines[us-1] != usernam && usernam != null)
                {
                    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
                    DialogResult result = new DialogResult();
                    result = MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password?", "Retry", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                    {

                        username.Clear();


                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you trying to check if the username value exist in a text file?

Comment: Yes, and if it does not exist display a message and return to main form so that user can re enter the text in it

Comment: I posted an answer tell me if it helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i think your problem is mostly checking if the value exist in the file. You can use this function to check if it exist or not and then you can do what you need :

```
public bool findValueInFile(string filePath, string value)
{
    //Get all lines from the txt file
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);            

    //Go thru all the lines
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
        //If we find the line we're looking for
        if (line.Equals(value))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //If we haven't found anything return false
    return false;
}
```

After calling this function depending on the return you can show a messagebox or do something else :

```
if(findValueInFile(yourPath, yourValue))
{
    // We found the value
}
else
{
    // We didn't find the value
}
```